# jQuery/Ajax help - Load page in div, update page in div, and clicking

Tags: jquery, ajax, pagination

I have a div where a page is loaded in it with a list of data from a database. The goal is to have the list split in pages and to navigate the pages by clicking a link without a page refresh.

The following code loads the page in the div, updates the page in the div, but only allows the click on page load. I'm not sure how to allow the clicking when updates happen in the div. Basically I can click to page 2, but can't click back to page 1 or go on to page 3. Clicking results in nothing. The links correctly link to page 1 and page 3 when I go to page 2. I don't know how to apply the click function to both load and html.

```
$('#display-list').load('list.php', function() {
    $("#list-next-page").click(function(){
        var page=$("#list-next-page").val();
            $.ajax({
                url:'list.php?page_id=' + page,
                method:'GET',
                data:{
                    page:page,
                },
                success:function(data){
                    $('#display-list').html(data);
                }
            });
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing something like the following seems to work:

```
$('#display-list').load('list.php', function() {
    $("#list-next-page").click(handleClick);
}); 

function handleClick(){
        var page=$("#list-next-page").val();
        $.ajax({
            url:'list.php?page_id=' + page,
            method:'GET',
            data:{
                page:page,
            },
            success:function(data){
                $('#display-list').html(data);
                $("#list-next-page").click(handleClick);
                $("#list-prev-page").click(handleClick);
            }
     });    
}
```

I do have to modify it to correctly pass the page numbers for next and previous links.